# Cannot read property 'Memory' of undefined, Terraformer.GeoStore, Terraformer.Store.Memory, Terraformer

Tags: javascript, gis

Cannot read property 'Memory' of undefined,   Terraformer.GeoStore, Terraformer.Store.Memory, Terraformer
I get error:

```
                  Cannot read property 'Memory' of undefined

                 html:

                  // not work
                 <script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer"></script>
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer-geostore"></script>
                 <script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer-rtree"></script>
                    <script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer-geostore-memory"></script>


                 // not work
                    <script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer@1.0.7"></script>
                         <script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer-geostore@1.0.4/browser/terraformer-geostore.js"></script>    


                  js:   Cannot read property 'Memory' of undefined
                           // create a new GeoStore using Memory and an RTree Index
                               var store = new Terraformer.GeoStore({
                               store: new Terraformer.Store.Memory(),   // error  Cannot read property 'Memory' of undefined
                                index: new Terraformer.RTree()
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The document have wrong code !!!!! take me 3 hours to figure out why

see picture below

```
           store: new Terraformer.Store.Memory(),
```

is wrong,

Correct code should be:

```
           store: new Terraformer.GeoStore.Memory(),
```

http://terraformer.io/geostore/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use terraformer in web worker, 
you must change source code to be able to let it work in web worker.

In browser UI main thread, no need to change source code.

I mean, if in browser, no need change source code, you can do:

```
           <script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer@1.0.7"></script>
           <script src="https://unpkg.com/terraformer-geostore@1.0.4/browser/terraformer-geostore.js"></script>


            // create a new GeoStore using Memory and an RTree Index
           var store = new Terraformer.GeoStore({

                //wrong, document:  store: new Terraformer.Store.Memory(),

                  store: new Terraformer.GeoStore.Memory(),
                    index: new Terraformer.RTree()
            });
```

But if in web worker, you must change source code:

```
              // must use our customized version,  'window' is not available in web worker scope. 
               // 'window ' only available in UI main thread, so   if(typeof window === "object"),   must change to 
               //  if(typeof WorkerGlobalScope === "function")

               //importScripts('https://unpkg.com/terraformer@1.0.9')    // original
               importScripts('../../utility/terraformer/terraformer.js') 


                 console.log('typeof WorkerGlobalScope - ', (typeof WorkerGlobalScope))  // function
                 console.log('typeof window - ', (typeof window))     // undefined
                 console.log('typeof navigator - ', (typeof navigator))    // object
```

This is customized code , terraformer.js  for web worker only.
[image]